# Why is Random forcing with $\mathbb{R}$, $2^\omega$, $\omega^\omega$ all the same?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

By random forcing, I mean the partial order of Borel sets of the given space, modulo Lebesgue null sets, ordered by inclusion. I can not find a source proving that all these partial orders are forcing equivalent. Can anyone provide a source or mention why? Thanks.

Comment: Being uncountable Polish spaces, they are all Borel-isomorphic. See for instance here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Polish+space#borel_isomorphism_between_polish_spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X, Y$ be two of the spaces you mention. Then we can construct a Borel function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ such that for some null set $N\subset X$, $f\upharpoonright X\setminus N$ is a bijection between $X\setminus N$ and $Y$.

Now given a condition $p$ in $R_Y$ (the random forcing associated to $Y$), consider $f^{-1}(p)$. This is a condition in $R_X$ (keep in mind that Borel functions are measurable!), and embeds $R_Y$ into $R_X$ densely.

Comment: You should add that $f$ preserves and reflects the property of having measure zero.  Without that, it wouldn't be well-defined on the measure algebra (or, equivalently, it wouldn't send forcing conditions to forcing conditions).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I'm sure thats enough information for me to be able to find a proof somewhere, but just in case, if you see this message and remember where I can find the proof, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the three spaces you mentioned are Borel isomorphic isn't enough. As Blass commented, the point is that the Borel isomorphism can be chosen to be null preserving which implies that the measure algebras are pairwise isomorphic.

Random forcing refers to forcing with (an atomless) measure algebra - For example the measure algebra on the product measure space $2^{\kappa}$. Measure algebras were characterized by [Maharam's theorem](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078424/pdf/pnas01638-0046.pdf). The measure algebras of the standard measures on $\mathbb{R}, 2^{\omega}, \omega^{\omega}$ are each of Maharam type $\aleph_0$ and hence isomorphic as Boolean algebras.